# Angular: different content and layout based on the customer

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, project, modularity, project-structure

I'm developing a web-application with angular and this will be used for different customers. Each customer has his own needs (specific functionality) and style (css). A lot of the functionality is shared though.

What I'm looking for is a total solution to keep this project clean and maintainable. The code will be running on the local server of each customer and the customers shouldn't see the specific code for the other customers (with other words, something like grunt should have filtered the deployment).

What I had in mind:

- Define different tasks in grunt to watch, build, etc per customer
- Define parent controllers (~inheritance) and parent views to share functionality
- Use a subfolder for each customer

  - e.g. views:

    - app/views/general/home.html (loads main.tpl.html)
    - app/views/customer1/main.tpl.html
    - app/views/customer2/main.tpl.html
  - e.g. controllers:

    - app/scripts/controllers/general/...
    - app/scripts/controllers/customer1/... (extends general controllers)
  - e.g. css

    - app/styles/general/...
    - app/styles/customer1/...

Grunt will select only the files relevant for the customer and should remove the customer-related paths. (e.g. both app/views/customer1/ and app/views/customer2/ should go to app/views/customer, which is loaded by app/views/general/home.html)

A big disadvantage will be that the app/views/general/home.html will have a reference to unexisting file while developing. The same goes for index.html where I need to include the controllers from the target dist folder, not from the project folder structure (while developing). Which makes everything a bit less readable and logical.

Do you think this is a good approach? Are there optimizations or alternatives coming to mind? Do you know of any grunt modules or angular modules aiding for such set-up?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One approach you could use is to run a basic node server that will store and serve up, using a rest call, the user preferences. So you would save user specific settings such as layout, etc and update these in a simple JSON file stored on a local or remote node server.

Comment: This would require to have all controllers/html pages/css classes for each customer available at each of the curstomer's server,s which is not allowed in our case. I could use configuration file, but I would need a solution for the controllers, html and css anyway..

Comment: This would merely be a template of sorts that defines certain parameters specific to the customer. Then based on those parameters you render a given set of templates, etc. Not hosting an individualised version at each customer base.